# How to calculate convex hull area using openCV functions?

Tags: c, opencv

I'm unable to find a working example of how to calculate the area of a convex hull using OpenCV. I saw one example that uses cvApproxPoly and cvContourArea, but I couldn't make it work. I have the following code.

```
IplImage* img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 500, 500 ), 8, 3 );


int i, count = rand()%100 + 1;
CvPoint pt0;

CvPoint* points = (CvPoint*)malloc( count * sizeof(points[0]));
int* hull = (int*)malloc( count * sizeof(hull[0]));
CvMat point_mat = cvMat( 1, count, CV_32SC2, points );
CvMat hull_mat  = cvMat( 1, count, CV_32SC1, hull );        
for( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
{
    pt0.x = rand() % (img->width/2) + img->width/4;
    pt0.y = rand() % (img->height/2) + img->height/4;
    points[i] = pt0;
}


CvSeq* convex_hull=cvConvexHull2( &point_mat, &hull_mat, CV_CLOCKWISE, 0 );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
    vector<Point2f> originalPoints;   // Your original points
    vector<Point2f> convexHull;  // Convex hull points 
    vector<Point2f> contour;  // Convex hull contour points        
    double epsilon = 0.001; // Contour approximation accuracy

    // Calculate convex hull of original points (which points positioned on the boundary)
    convexHull(Mat(originalPoints),convexHull,false);

    // Approximating polygonal curve to convex hull
    approxPolyDP(Mat(convexHull), contour, 0.001, true);

    cout << fabs(contourArea(Mat(contour)));
```

Comment: I quite don't see the need of converting into cv::Mat the std::vector(s): they are perfectly digested by convexHull, approxPolyDP and contourArea

Comment: @Pradeep Pati thanks for help, whats the difference between the convexHull and contour vector ? in my case its always the same vector of points ? as I understand the convexHull is polygonal curve by itself no ?

Answer (score 6):

Actually calculating the area of 2D convex hull is pretty easy. You integrate the area below each point going in clockwise direction.
Here is a simple code that does that. (Few first lines are definition and calculation of convex hull).

```
vector<Point2f> originalPoints;   // Your original points
vector<Point2f> ch;  // Convex hull points

// Calculate convex hull of original points (which points positioned on the boundary)
cv::convexHull(Mat(originalPoints),ch,false);
// false parameter is used to organize the points in clockwise direction

// Now calculate the area of sonvex hull 'ch':
double area = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ch.size(); i++){
    int next_i = (i+1)%(ch.size());
    double dX   = ch[next_i].x - ch[i].x;
    double avgY = (ch[next_i].y + ch[i].y)/2;
    area += dX*avgY;  // This is the integration step.
}
```

area = abs(area); // Area can be negative if integration was started from right to left.

Comment: You are right, although (thanks to you) I found another way to calculate the area of the 2d convex hull.

Answer (score 4):

use:
`CvSeq* convex_hull=cvConvexHull2( &point_mat, &hull_mat, CV_CLOCKWISE, **1** ); // !!`

my code:

```
 CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
 CvSeq* contours = 0;
 cvFindContours(bordImage, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour),
            CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

 for(CvSeq* seq = contours; seq != 0; seq = seq->h_next){
     cvDrawContours(dstImage, seq, CV_RGB(255,216,0), CV_RGB(0,0,250), 0, 1, 8);
 }

CvMemStorage* hullStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
for(CvSeq* seq = contours; seq != 0; seq = seq->h_next){
    CvSeq *hulls = cvConvexHull2(seq, hullStorage, CV_CLOCKWISE, 1);
    cvDrawContours(dstImage, hulls, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), CV_RGB(100, 0, 0), 0, 1, 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < hulls->total; i++) {
        CvPoint* p = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem ( hulls, i );
         // ...
    }
    cvClearMemStorage(hullStorage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV 2.4.9:

```
double computeConvexHullArea(vector<Point> originalPoints)
{
    vector<Point> hull;
    convexHull(originalPoints, hull);

    return contourArea(hull);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For OpenCV python:

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(cntr)  #cntr is the contour
convex_hull_area = cv2.contourArea(hull)
```