# Problems in finding contours and convex hull in openCV

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, convex-hull

I have written the following code

```
#include"opencv2/opencv.hpp"

 #include<iostream>
 #include<math.h>
 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

main()
{
Mat img1,img2,sub,gray1,gray2,lab,ycbcr;
int v[3];

int row,col,i,j,t;
VideoCapture cap(0);

namedWindow("current");

cap>>img1;
sub=img1;

row=img1.rows;
col=img1.cols;

cvtColor(img1,gray1,CV_BGR2GRAY);


vector<vector<Point> > cont;

vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

while (1) {

    cap>>img2;

    cvtColor(img2,gray2,CV_BGR2GRAY);


    for(i=0;i<row;++i)
    {
        for (j=0; j<col; ++j)
        {


            if(abs(gray1.at<uchar>(i,j) - gray2.at<uchar>(i,j))>10)
            {
                sub.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = img2.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
                sub.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = img2.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
                sub.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = img2.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];

            }
            else
            {

                sub.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]=0;
                sub.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1]=0;
                sub.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2]=0;
            }

        }


    }


    cvtColor(sub,ycbcr,CV_BGR2YCrCb);

    inRange(ycbcr,Scalar(7,133,106),Scalar(255,178,129),ycbcr);
    findContours(ycbcr,cont,hierarchy,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Scalar color = CV_RGB(255,0,0);
    for(int i1 = 0 ;i1 >= 0; i1 = hierarchy[i1][0] )
    drawContours( ycbcr, cont, i1, color,2, CV_AA, hierarchy );



    vector<Point2f > hullPoints;
  // convexHull(Mat(cont),hullPoints,false);
    imshow("current",ycbcr);
```

a
        if(waitKey(33)=='q')
            break;
        img1=img2.clone();
    }

}

1.)Why the contours are not displaying in red color although i specified it through CV_RGB(255,0,0).
2.)When i uncomment the line
        convexHull(Mat(cont),hullPoints,false);
,the program shows runtime error.Why is it happening.Can anybody tell me the exact format of convexHull()
and the meaning of its arguments

Answer (score 2):

1) Try (0,0,255) for red color. OpenCV uses BGR format.

2) For finding convex hull, try the code in [OpenCV tutorial.](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html#convex-hull)

Also try similar question as yours on Convexhull. [How to calculate convex hull area using openCV functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471023/how-to-calculate-convex-hull-area-using-opencv-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Your hullPoints vector is empty. If you check the size of vector,you don't get an error.

```
if(hullPoints.size() > 2) {
  convexHull(....);
 }
```