# Using opencv convexHul Get area of given points. - Errors occurred during points to Mat conversion

Tags: c++, opencv

I followed [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/d7a/convexhull_8cpp-example.html) link to make vector of points. In order to calculate the area of given points i used convex hull. To do that i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471023/how-to-calculate-convex-hull-area-using-opencv-functions). When i try to calculate the area inside the convexHull,  Following Error is occurred. As i noticed after converting vector point into Mat,  There is no depth.  `CV_Assert(total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S));`
 How do i overcome this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    vector<Point2d> originalPoints;
    vector<Point2d> hull;
    vector<Point2f> contour;
    double epsilon = 0.001;

    for(int dataPointCount=0; dataPointCount < 10; dataPointCount++)
    {
        cv::Point2d point;
        point.x = 10 * ( (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX ) + 2; // just genarate random point
        point.y = 5 * ( (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX ) + 2;
        originalPoints.push_back(point);

    }

    convexHull(Mat(originalPoints) , hull , true);
    approxPolyDP(Mat(hull), contour, 0.001, true);
    cout << "====>"<< fabs(contourArea(Mat(contour)));

    return 0;
}
```

Error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)) in convexHull, file /home/ve/workspace/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp, line 136
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/ve/workspace/opencv-3.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp:136: error: (-215) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function convexHull
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the function `convexHull` requires the points coordinates stored as floats instead of double. To overcome this issue change the definitions of your vectors into:

```
vector<Point2f> originalPoints;
vector<Point2f> hull;
vector<Point2f> contour;
```